# Handler tap of UISegmentControl to order data by ASC and DESC

Tags: ios, objective-c, listener, uisegmentedcontrol

I try to handler 2 tap on a `UISegmentControl` without success. 
I add a target to my listener with  `UIControlEventValueChanged` and it work but only if the segment is not selected.

That my function that handle tap, the target is made with the storyboard:

```
- (IBAction)changeFilterAction:(UISegmentedControl *)paramSender {
    NSInteger selectedIndex = [_segmentControlFilter selectedSegmentIndex];
    NSLog(@"Test");
}
```

To resume:

I try to ORDERBY data by ASC and DESC. When i tap for the first time i post a ASC request and i would like that when i tap for the second time it post DESC request.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you post your code? Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve from your question.

Comment: I add but i don't think that it 'll be useful

Comment: What are you trying to do? Detect which segment has been selected? Handle a double tap from a recogniser?

Comment: I try to ORDERBY data by ASC and DESC. When i tap for the first time i post a ASC request and i would like that when i tap for the second time it post DESC request.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a UIButton for this? Is there anything else on the UISegmentedControl?

Comment: Yes because i add in runtime the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out by checking the option `Momentary`. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will try to add Custom `UIButton` with clear color and place it to the `UISegmentControl`.

For Example :

```
UIButton * overButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, segControl.frame.size.width/numOfSegments, segControl.frame.size.height)];

[overButton addTarget:segControl action:@selector(overTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];            

[segControl addSubview:overButton];

//Adjust your `overButton` frame as per your selected Segment index
```

Thanks!